# Keras DataGenerator: How to load only a specific number of images from each sub-directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using Keras flow_from_directory to load images from multiple folders. The number of images per folder varies from 1500 to 9500. As per my understanding, keras ImageDataGenerator loads all the images in a subfolder but I want to load only 1000 images from each subfolder.

To give an example, my directory structure is as follows: A is the parent directory, and within A there are X1, X2,...,Xn subdirectories. And I wish to sample only 1000 images each from X1, X2, ...,Xn, i.e., in total I will have 1000*n images.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.list_files`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#list_files) for all groups separately, `take` 1000 images from each, and concatenate the datasets.

```
import tensorflow as tf

dogs = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('Dogs/*.jpg').take(1000)
cats = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('Cats/*.jpg').take(1000)
turtles = tf.data.Dataset.list_files('Turtles/*.jpg').take(1000)

ds = dogs.concatenate(cats).concatenate(turtles).shuffle(3000)
```

This will give you file names. Then, you can use functions like [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images#using_tfdata_for_finer_control) to transform them into pairs of images, labels.

```
def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(file_path, os.path.sep)
  one_hot = parts[-2] == class_names
  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

def decode_img(img):
  img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, [img_height, img_width])
  return img

def process_path(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img, label


train_ds = ds.map(process_path)
```

If you have many folders, you can do something like:

```
all_folders = os.listdir('/all_images')

all_datasets = dict()
for folder in all_folders:
    all_datasets[folder] = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(folder +'/*.jpg').take(1000)

ds = all_datasets.pop('Dogs')

for key, dataset in all_datasets.items():
    ds = ds.concatenate(dataset)

ds = ds.shuffle(len(all_datasets)*1000)
```

Something like that, I'm not sure it runs I wrote it directly on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. It is a good approach to solve the problem but I have two reservations. In my case, I have nearly 100 sub-directories (labels) that will make sampling manually very cumbersome. Second, I would also like to use functions like flip, zoom, etc. provided in the ImageDataGenerator. I am wondering if there is a way to write a custom data generator or modify __get_item or __len__ to get the work done?

Comment: When reading the images in the function, you can use things like `tf.image.random_brightness` for image augmentation. And the 100 directories can be done automatically by iterating through a dict containing all `tf.data.dataset.list_files`.

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas. I tried your code but at train_ds = ds.map(process_path) it gives me the following error: TypeError: Value passed to parameter 'input' has DataType string not in list of allowed values: float32, float64, int32, uint8, int16, int8, complex64, int64, qint8, quint8, qint32, bfloat16, uint16, complex128, float16, uint32, uint64, bool

Comment: I think this error is from here:  return tf.argmax(one_hot)

Comment: Try `one_hot = tf.cast(parts[-2] == class_names, tf.int32)` and you'll need to define class names as the name of your folders.